# Conditional coloring using graphics in Mathematica

Tags: graphics, wolfram-mathematica

Please consider :

```
dalist = {{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 3}, {4, 4, 4}, {5, 5, 5}, 
          {1, 2, 1}, {2, 3, 1}, {3, 4, 1}, {4, 5, 1}, {5, 6, 1}}
```

I use the following to plot the above where `#2` & `#3` are x & y coordinates

```
Graphics@MapThread[Point[{#2, #3}] &, Transpose@dalist]
```

[image]

- `#1` a timing reference I
  would like to use to color the
  points.
- It can range from 1 to 30 in my data.
- `#1 =1` should always yield to the
  same color.

**EDIT : Building-up on solutions below**

- How could I set the color range/gradient manually or use an existing one ("BlackBodySpectrum") ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
datlist = Flatten[Table[{i, j + i, j}, {i, 1, 20}, {j, 1, 20}], 1];
colordata = 60; (* Try different palettes 1 .. 62 *)

Graphics[(Sequence @@ 
     {Directive[ 
      ColorData[colordata][Mod[#[[1]], ColorData[colordata, "Range"][[2]]]]], 
     PointSize -> Large, Point[{#[[2]], #[[3]]}]} & /@ datlist), 
     Frame -> True]
```

[image]

**Edit**

Using `BlackBodySpectrum`:

```
datlist = Flatten[Table[{i, j + i, j}, {i, 1, 20}, {j, 1, 20}], 1];
colordata = "BlackBodySpectrum";(*Try different palettes 1.. 62*)
Graphics[(
  Sequence @@ {Directive[
       ColorData[
         colordata][#[[1]] ColorData[colordata, 
            "Range"][[2]]/(Length@datlist/
            Length@Select[datlist, #[[1]] == 1 &])]], 
      PointSize -> Large, Point[{#[[2]], #[[3]]}]} & /@ datlist), 
 Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ColorData`:

```
Graphics@MapThread[{ColorData[1][#1], Point[{#2, #3}]} &, 
  Transpose@dalist]
```

Answer (score 2):

No need for MapThread

```
Graphics[{PointSize -> 0.05, {ColorData[1][#1], Point[{#2, #3}]} & @@@dalist}]
```

[image]

You can roll your own image gradients using `Blend`:

```
Graphics[{PointSize -> 0.05, 
         {Blend[{Red, Yellow, Blue}, #1/5], Point[{#2, #3}]} & @@@ dalist}]
```

Please note that you have to take care yourself of scaling your data range so that the maximum value generates 1 and the minimum 0 (if you want to optimally use the available range)

[image]